# mysql datetime YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ covert it to mysql ORDERBY

Tags: mysql, datetime

I need to store a specific time format in sql so I can ORDER BY later . The format that I have is YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSZ (e.g., 2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z) which doesn't seem to be neither unix time or mysql date format . I'm using PHP get the time from a webservice which provides it in this format .

Comment: The time is already in a format for which the lexicographical ordering is the same as logical ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strtotime` can parse that datetime string into a timestamp, which you can then format as desired.

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (datecol) VALUES ('$date')";
```

Answer (score 0):

First, convert the date (which looks to me like ISO 8601 format) to a PHP timestamp

```
$datetime = strtorime("2004-08-04T19:09:02.768Z");
```

Then the SQL date format is

```
date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", $datetime);
```